Washing machine temp changes in its own from normal to hot then normal again
I’ve had my washing machine for 14 years and it works great until it randomly decides to switch all cold settings to scalding hot. The hot setting becomes cold and all other settings are various degrees of hot/warm. All rinse cycles are programmed to run cold (which I can’t change) and that ends up being super hot rinses. After a various amount of time, it goes back to normal. Sometimes it corrects itself after one or two loads but now it’s lasting longer. Clearly there’s a sensor issue but I’m not sure what part. It’s a Whirlpool compact YWET3300SQ2

Clearly there’s a sensor issue ... that is not clear at all ... it could be the part of the control circuit that selects which valve to open
